# get the right index onTapGesture with AsyncImage

Tags: swiftui

While iterating over images and loading AsyncImages, the `.onTapGesture` does not refer to the clicked element.

Is this due to View refresh on image loading? How to bypass this issue?

```swift
var images: [String] = [
    "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/small_montgenevre_eglise.jpg",
    "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/small_montgenevre_brousset.jpg",
    "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/small_montgenevre_sommet-ts-crete.jpg",
    "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/mega_mtgenevre_sommet-des-gondrans.jpg"
]

struct thumbnail: View {
    
    @State var mainImageUrl: String = images[0];
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: mainImageUrl)) { image in
                image
                    .resizable().scaledToFit().frame(height: 350)
            } placeholder: {
                ProgressView()
            }.frame(height: 350).cornerRadius(10)
            HStack {
                ForEach(images, id: \.self) { imageUrl in
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: imageUrl)) { sourceImage in
                        sourceImage
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                            .clipped()
                    } placeholder: {
                        ProgressView()
                    }.onTapGesture {
                        self.mainImageUrl = imageUrl
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sort of works if you just flip the `frame` and `aspectRatio` as in the code below.
However it is very slow and you are constantly re-downloading the images whenever you click on a thumbnail.
The last image is specially slow.

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Thumbnail()
    }
}

struct Thumbnail: View {
    
    var images: [String] = [
        "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/small_montgenevre_eglise.jpg",
        "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/small_montgenevre_brousset.jpg",
        "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/small_montgenevre_sommet-ts-crete.jpg",
        "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/mega_mtgenevre_sommet-des-gondrans.jpg"
    ]

    @State var mainImageUrl: String = "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/small_montgenevre_eglise.jpg"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: mainImageUrl)) { image in
                image.resizable().scaledToFit().frame(height: 350)
            } placeholder: {
                ProgressView()
            }.frame(height: 350).cornerRadius(10)
            HStack  { 
                ForEach(images, id: \.self) { imageUrl in
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: imageUrl)) { sourceImage in
                        sourceImage
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)   // <--- here
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)  // <--- here
                            .clipped()
                    } placeholder: {
                        ProgressView()
                    }.onTapGesture {
                        self.mainImageUrl = imageUrl
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IMHO, a better way is to use a different approach to avoid the constant downloading of images.
You could download the pictures in `parallel` only once, using swift async/await concurrency.
Such as in this code:

```
struct Thumbnail: View {
    @StateObject var loader = ImageLoader()
    @State var selectedPhoto: PhotoImg?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if loader.images.count < 1 {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                Image(uiImage: selectedPhoto?.image ?? UIImage(systemName: "smiley")!)
                    .frame(height: 350).cornerRadius(10)
                ScrollView {
                    HStack (spacing: 10) {
                        ForEach(loader.images) { photo in
                            Image(uiImage: photo.image)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    selectedPhoto = photo
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    if let first = loader.images.first {
                        selectedPhoto = first
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await loader.loadParallel()
        }
    }
    
}

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var images: [PhotoImg] = []
    
    let urls: [String] = [
        "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/small_montgenevre_eglise.jpg",
        "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/small_montgenevre_brousset.jpg",
        "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/small_montgenevre_sommet-ts-crete.jpg",
        "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/mega_mtgenevre_sommet-des-gondrans.jpg"
    ]

    func loadParallel() async {
        return await withTaskGroup(of: (String, UIImage).self) { group in
            for str in urls {
                if let url = URL(string: str) {
                    group.addTask { await (url.absoluteString, self.loadImage(url: url)) }
                }
            }
            for await result in group {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.images.append(PhotoImg(url: result.0, image: result.1))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadImage(url: URL) async -> UIImage {
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            if let img = UIImage(data: data) { return img }
        }
        catch { print(error) }
        return UIImage()
    }
}

struct PhotoImg: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var url: String
    var image: UIImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was very useful. Thanks. I simply had to lines flipped:

```
.scaledToFill()
.frame(width: 80, height: 80)
```

Yet it seemed those two lines in the order presented above caused this to work properly. Any idea why this is the case?